# Convection microwave oven in office setting?

Tags: convection

Our office recently moved and we have no break room, i am trying (unsuccessfully) to convince them to get a convection microwave oven.  Is there something i need to know about putting one in a space not designed for cooking?  They want a microwave and i want more, but is it safe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Health & Safety, not about cooking.

Comment: it's more related to electrical engineering.

Comment: NWatson, I don't think we can answer your question here.  It's not that it's completely off-topic, it's just that apparently nobody here has the knowledge. Maybe try one of the other Stack Exchanges, such as Electrical Engineering or Home Improvement.

Comment: if it's sold legit, then it's presumably safe, give instructions are followed.

Comment: Thank you, new to this site and i was not sure which direction to go, but i do appreciate all the replies